# Android and google login - get same ID as in OpenID login

Tags: c#, android, openid, dotnetopenauth

We want to build asp.net application which enables user login through Google OpenID provider. We are using `DotNetOpenAuth` library and we are able to login user correctly and as a result we get user identifier like:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

We are able to create or associated existing account on our side with google account.

We want to make android app which also enable users to login with their google account. To be able to authenticate user, we'd like to aquire same user identifier as shown above - is it possible?

If not, what is the best method to provide login for web app and mobile app with google?
We also integrate with facebook and twitter,

Comment: What are you sharing or accessing based on the login on your Android app?